# How to add currencies data to a customer in NetSuite using Suite Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have created a User Event Script to add currencies in a sublist while creating a new record. But my record is created but the currencies which I'm passing from code is not added to that record.

```
const currencies = ['GBP','USD','CAD','EUR'];
  // log.debug(currencies);
   var cnt = 1;
     if (currencies) {
        for (var key3 in currencies) {
           if (currencies[key3] >= cnt) {
             rec.insertLine({
             sublistId: "currency",
             line: cnt
             });
             log.debug(currencies[key3]);
             rec.setSublistValue({
             sublistId: "currency",
             fieldId: "currency",
             line: cnt,
             value: currencies[key3]
             });
           }
           cnt++;
         }
      log.debug(cnt);
    }
```

Comment: You are sure with the loop and condition. these are working fine? Check with putting the logs in between the code to identify that count is being perfect.

Comment: As I have checked it is not entering into if condition.So it is not inserting the line. By the way if you are updating any field in already existing line you need to use "updateLine" in place of insertLine.